# Getting the URL through `LegacyIAccessibleValue` fails on several computers

Tags: url, accessibility, ui-automation

I'm making a URL logging tool with UIAutomation.

I could get URL from `LegacyIAccessibleValue`, so I thought I had completed the development. But getting the URL fails on some computers.

And I found that `LegacyIAccessibleValue` and `ValueValue` are empty strings on those computers (check with Inspect.exe).

For example:

- on some computers -> LegacyIAccessible.value : "https://www.google.com"
- on some computers -> LegacyIAccessible.value : ""
  (I cannot attach a file because of company security.)

If anyone knows why then please tell me.

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Can you explain how `LegacyIAccessible`, which is part of the accessibility API, is related to logging? And what URLs do you want to log?

Comment: if FocusChanged event is occured, LegacyIAccessibleValue = URL, LegacyIAccessibleValue = tab title. (in case of 'Chrome')..  I want to log All URLs I've visited

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add what you mean by "on some computers"? Does it refer to tests *in Chrome* on different computers, or different applications (on different computers)? Browsers don't start their accessibility API by default, so that may be the reason why you get different results.